# Run two different R scripts at a time on windows

Tags: r

I have two R scripts. one is: `source("D:/source_code_CCA.r")` and another one is: `source("D:/source_code_DL.r")`. These two R scripts are completely independent. I want to run these two r scripts at a time on same R console on windows. How can I do this? Please help!

Comment: I want to run these two R scripts on same R session.

Comment: What you're asking per se it impossible given the nature of R's interpreter; it is linear and will wait from a step to finish before moving on to the next. You have interesting options in the answers provided below, I think that's as good as it gets.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new script containing the following lines, or execute them via interactive console -- after making sure that the directory containing `Rscript.exe` is in your `PATH`:

```
shell(cmd = 'Rscript.exe D:/source_code_cca.r', wait=FALSE)
shell(cmd = 'Rscript.exe D:/source_code_DL.r', wait=FALSE)
```

(If it's not already there, the value to add to path could be `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\bin` or `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\bin\x64`)

Note that if you use `cat`s or `message`s, those would be captured if you direct them to a text file, such as in:

```
shell(cmd = 'Rscript.exe D:/source_code_cca.r > out1.log', wait=FALSE)
shell(cmd = 'Rscript.exe D:/source_code_DL.r > out2.log', wait=FALSE)
```

Or if you specify `intern=TRUE` and assign the function's result to some variable:

```
res1 <- shell(cmd = 'Rscript.exe D:/source_code_cca.r', wait=FALSE, intern=TRUE)
res2 <- shell(cmd = 'Rscript.exe D:/source_code_DL.r', wait=FALSE, intern=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're using Windows, the path tells me :-)

1. Open two different `cmd.exe` windows.
2. Use the [R command](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Invoking-R-from-the-command-line) to call one of the script in the first window, and one for the second. This can be done with some minor magic like: `R.exe --no-environ --no-save > "out.txt"`

Hope that helps. Alternatively, you can spawn different processed if you want to call them within the same shell.